# How can I create the json string for the below dictionary

Tags: python, json

Can we create the `JSON` string for the following dictionary?

```
dict1  ={'name':'rahul','age':26,'location':'chennai'}
```

Please suggest me to create the `JSON` string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use built-in library `json`.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

```py
import json

dict1 = {'name': 'rahul', 'age': 26, 'location': 'chennai'}
json_str = json.dumps(dict1)

print(json_str)
```

output:

```py
{"name": "rahul", "age": 26, "location": "chennai"}
```